# Option to workaround "replot" in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

(1) I want to plot the following two functions. I know I can simply change the parameters for g(x) and use the command replot g(x) to plot both functions. But I am just wondering if there is any option to avoid "replot" command and use "something", so the parameters a and be wont be updated and both functions can be plotted?

```
f(x)=a*x**2+b*x
a=2
b=3
plot f(x)

<something>

g(x)=a*x**2+b*x
a=1
b=4
plot g(x)
```

(2) What if I do not know the parameter's values in advance during curve fitting in the following example?

```
 f(x)=a*x**2+b*x
 fit f(x) "filename" u 2 via a,b
 plot f(x)

    <something>

 g(x)=a*x**2+b*x
 fit g(x) "filename" u 2 via a,b
 plot g(x)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you meant, but:

```
f(x, a, b)=a*x**2 + b*x
plot f(x,2,3), f(x,1,4)
```

should do the trick ...

Comment: exactly that was what I wanted! Thanks. With that I am wondering what if I do not know the parameter values in advance, for example, during data fitting, how to accomplish it? I have added it as second part of my question.